# Ros2 Galactic Nav2 - /scan offering incompatible QoS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Got below messages while trying Nav2 setup and rviz didnt show the scan

```
New subscription discovered on topic '/scan', requesting incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY

[rviz2-5] [WARN] [1639275375.691911822] [rviz2]: New publisher discovered on topic '/scan', offering incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY

[gazebo-1] [WARN] [1639275575.651314019] [depth_camera_controller]: New subscription discovered on topic '/depth_camera/image_raw', requesting incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY

[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1639275575.682572775] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED

[rviz2-5] [WARN] [1639275575.697367400] [rviz2]: New publisher discovered on topic '/depth_camera/image_raw', offering incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392676/ros2-galactic-nav2---/scan-offering-incompatible-qos/) by [Manirajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/91435/manirajan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-12-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to change the QoS in Rviz to best effort, since it uses sensor data QoS.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2022-02-02**:
I am just gonna add that this is done in the side panel, under the Topic -> Reliability Policy parameter. https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/187#issuecomment-810105698